# Statistical power in R as in Stata

Tags: r, stata

So I'm taking a statistical course at the moment. And one assignment is to create a plot like seen below. My professor uses the Stata program, and have said that it pretty much can be done my the following command:

```
power twomeans 0 5 , sd1(9) sd2(9) alpha(0.05) power(0.90)
```

I am not using Stata, so I don't have the option to do that command. But I have been using R for all other exercises where I have been able to pretty much replicate everything. But not this time. I have searched and searched, but there doesn't seem to be any simple command to create this. So am I just missing something, I do I actually have to build it myself ?

[image]

Comment: have you had a look at the `pwr` package?

Comment: Ah, that looks fun. Thank you very much :)